# How to make a referral system?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850962/how-to-count-clicks-on-a-get-value-with-php

I would like to create a referral system in which every new visitor gets his own unique link like http://example.com/?ref=12345. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: This seems like just simple database work to me... is there something specific that you're having trouble with?

Comment: This is not really a question. You won't be able to build your 'referral system' without at least a basic notion of php. If you DID have a basic notion, you would not ask this. Furthermore,  even if you DO get a decent answer (which I doubt),  you still won't be able to implement it with at least a minimum knowledge of php.  ( Flagged as question without a purpose. )

Answer (score 0):

How about this

$id = md5($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"])

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/?ref='.$id);
```

I would also save this in a cookie because the IP address might change!!!